# get jquery ajax response outside of success handler

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I know I can do this by setting `async: false`, but doing so will defeat the purpose of Ajax (this will no longer be Ajax anymore as this will lock my browser until the request is complete). Is it possible AT ALL to get the response from an Ajax request outside of the `success` handler without setting `async: false`?

Please let me know if this is possible

Thank you

Comment: why would you want such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a callback because of the way asynchronous calls work. I don't think there's a way of directly getting the data without blocking.